# Use variables in document.querySelector

Tags: javascript

If I have:

```
<div class="test" data-name="Paul" >
```

and

```
var name = "Paul";
```

Can I use `document.querySelector` to do something like this?

```
document.querySelector("[data-name=name]");
```

This doesn't work. What do I have to do?

Comment: Uhhhhh... `"[data-name="+name+"]"`, maybe?

Comment: that's not a variable, that's a string literal.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.test')` or `document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0]` if you have a class, why would you want to use an unconventional way?

Comment: No man, there are a lot's of elements with class 'test', I have to select with data-name

Comment: Reopening because escaping CSS identifiers is not covered by the other question.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can do that, but you need to use [the `CSS.escape()` function](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#the-css.escape%28%29-method) to ensure the value is properly encoded for use in a CSS expression.

```
var name = "hello, world!";
document.querySelector("[data-name=" + CSS.escape(name) + "]");
```

```
<div data-name=​"hello, world!">​…</div>
```

ES2015:

```
const name = "hello, world!";
document.querySelector(`[data-name=${CSS.escape(name)}]`);
```

If you don't use `CSS.escape(...)` then certain values of `name` could cause your code to throw an error instead.

```
var name = "hello, world!";
document.querySelector("[data-name=" + name + "]");
```

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[data-name=hello, world!]' is not a valid selector
```

If you're targeting a browser which doesn't natively support `CSS.escape()` you can use [this polyfill by Mathias Bynens](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/CSS.escape).

Answer (score 8):

You need to concatenate the strings, like:

`document.querySelector("[data-name=" + name + "]");`

For example:

(See @Jeremy Bank's answer for a much better answer, tho)

```js
var name = "Paul";
var element = document.querySelector("[data-name=" + name + "]");

alert(element.nodeName);
```

```html
<div class="test" data-name="Paul">
  test.
</div>
```

Comment: Only if the value of `name` is a [CSS identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

Comment: fair comment, thx - directing readers to the better answer that handles the case when it's not a CSS Identifier

Answer (score 5):

you could also do this

```
let name = 'Paul'
document.querySelector('.'+ name)
```

then you do not need a data-name

Comment: It will not work - use of "." - indicate that you are trying to grab div with class - Paul - and div does not have that class

Answer (score 0):

This works in Typescript:

```js
document.querySelector(\`[data-name=${name}]`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="test" data-name="Paul"></div>
```

Try in this way it may be work :-

```
var username = "Paul";

document.querySelector(`[data-name="${username}"]`);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm super late to this party but check out the code snippet - it shows you how to get the current value of data-name and also how to change the value

```js
    let test = document.querySelector('.test');
    // get the current value of data-name
    let name = test.dataset.name;
    console.log('current value of data-name: ' + name)

    // change the value of data-name
    let newName = 'Jimmy'
    console.log(test.dataset.name = newName);
```

```html
<div class="test" data-name="Paul"></div>
```